# Fubini's theorem , change integrals?

Tags: calculus

the exercice says that :

\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^{p-1}} \int_0^{1/x}\frac{|\ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p} \,dt\,dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^1 \frac{|\ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p} \int_0^1\frac{1}{x^{p-1}} \,dx\,dt + \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{|\ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p} \int_0^{1/t}\frac{1}{x^{p-1}} \, dx \, dt
\end{align}

but what i found is this :

\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^{p-1}}\int_{0}^{1/x}\frac{|\ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p} \, dt \, dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^1 \frac{|\ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^{p-1}} \, dx \, dt + \int_0^{1/t}\frac{1}{x^{p-1}} \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{|\ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p} \, dt \, dx
\end{align}

so my question is for the last integral ,, is it equal to the one in the first equality , i mean can we use fubini here , because The symbol t is a dummy integration variable and cannot appear as an integration limit of the outer integral, or where is the eror

Answer (score 0):

All functions considered are positive and measurable, so Fubini always applies without any extra justification. It is when your functions might be negative that you need to worry about integrability to apply Fubini.

Hope that helps,